# Concatenating n Lists returned by function

Tags: scala

Most likely easy problem but I can't find a way out:

- I have a function `go(a,b,c): List`
- and another `List list1` that I'm iterating

  ```
  val result = List[]()

  for(t<- list1){ result = result ::: go(a,b,t)}
  ```

Now obviously this does not work because val is immutable but is there a way to return a List like this?

Comment: Maybe just use `var`? Or maybe you just want `list1.flatMap(t => go(a,b,t))`

Comment: This is it thx very much I guess I should have rather tried again tomorrow :D But you saved my night.